# I am trying to run i386 executable on Mac Silcon M1 Rosetta terminal -- but its says 'Bad CPU type in executable'

Tags: cpu, executable, apple-m1, i386, rosetta

The executable is sm (for SuperMongo plotting routine)

=======

file sm
sm: Mach-O executable i386

so if its a valid i386 executable (which is working smoothly on older Macs)

## sm
zsh: bad CPU type in executable: sm

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks --- I didnt understand "provide enough code" -- I can send the executable file as email attachment to anyone -- if you can provide the email id. Please note that older Macs show i386 on terminal if you type arch -- new Mac with M1 chip shows arm64 on typing arch on the native terminal -- and i386 on the rosetta terminal -- so its exactly the same i386 on new Mac? Then it should work but it says 'bad CPU type in executable' Ranjan Gupta